# Drupal 7 Change User Login block link text

Tags: 7, users

I've set up the standard "User Login" block to the "header" region of my theme. I clicked on "configure" and selected "Link" under "Block Type". Now the link to sign in appears as "Log In/Register". How do I change this text?
I have also LoginToboggan enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of throwing a string override directly into settings.php file, use the excellent [String Overrides](http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides/) module. It can help you to manage the string overrides for your login link, as well as possible future UI text changes. All this without hacking core files.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a template, probably named something like 'user-login.tpl.php'

For more information on 'working with template suggestions' have a look at http://drupal.org/node/223440

Comment: Yes, I'd use that to customize the actual form view. But I need to change the text of the link to the sign in form.

Comment: Sorry, I get what you mean now. You could put string overrides directly into code in the settings.php file for the site. If you look through this file you will find a section that is commented out that looks like this (around line 448):

$conf['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = array(
'Log In/Register' => 'Log In',
);

You can add any strings you want to replace here.